# External configuration file for Indesign Plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign

I'm developing a JavaScript plugin for Indesign CS5 and I would like to be capable of configuring it from an external file (an XML one for example).
Is-it possible? I haven't found anything on Adobe website or web searches...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a technicality, when trying to interact with InDesign via JavaScript, it's not referred to as a plugin. An InDesign plugin is developed in c++, compiled to a .InDesignPlugin file and loaded into InDesign at startup time.

On to the actual question, assuming you are refferring to an InDesign Script (.jsx format): Yes, it's possible. The most basic way is to do it using the base JavaScript File class. Example:

```
File inFile = new File("c:\temp\testfile.txt");
inFile.open("r");
String oneChar = inFile.readch();
String fiveChars = inFile.read(5);
String oneLine = inFile.readln();
```

However, with this way it takes quite a bit of work to parse an xml config file. For this purpose you would be better off using a library that someone else made. jQuery includes functionality for this, or you could go for the more specialized library [`XML for <SCRIPT>`](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to parse an XML using E4X syntax.